# Kendo UI Documentation unavailable, unable to connect to code.jquery.com

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Since yesterday I have been trying to access Kendo UI documentation (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/introduction) , but the site was not loading.. When analyzed the network traffic, its making request to code.jquery.com, which was not available. Tried to ping http://code.jquery.com - couldn't connect, request timed out.

Wondering, if any Kendo UI documentation user noticed it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: we are able to access the links.. I guess it is the intranet/proxy settings on your machine.

Comment: It's you: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/introduction

Comment: Thanks Kanchirk and Vash.. It was our firewall. Networking guys fixed it now. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It was firewall. Thanks all for your input.